# How to stop Wordpress TinyMCE from stripping content of empty html tags e.g. <div class="any class"></div>

Tags: html, css, wordpress, tinymce

I'm displaying some content in two columns in a Wordpress post, so I've got two divs displaying half each:

```
<div class="half">Left column.</div>
<div class="half last">Right column.</div>
```

But of course I also need to clear this, which I usually do with this afterwards:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

but this keeps getting stripped out whenever I save the article or view the visual editor as well as any other empty html tags e.g. icons. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I'd recommend using the Clearfix technique:

See:

- [Webtoolkit](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)
- [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/)

Comment: I don't like anything that's a hack, is there no way to keep the element in the page?

Comment: Its really common practice in CSS, much less of a hack that adding additional markup to your HTML purely to cause a clear. I'm afraid I can't directly answer why wordpress is doing this to you.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to add a clearfix class, but if you absolutely must have that extra empty element, add &nbsp; to the clear div.  WordPress is stripping out the empty div.

Comment: Unfortunatley this only worked until I saved the post. Editing and resaving converted the &npsp into a normal space the 2nd time it was saved, and then deleted the div as before. Not ideal, as I'm planning some future edits to this post.

Answer (score 0):

There's a plugin which adds a button to print `<br style="clear: both;">` to the page. This markup won't get stripped out (see https://codex.wordpress.org/Wrapping_Text_Around_Images#Clear_The_Display).

See this answer on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com for a link to the plugin: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/255386/48203

Answer (score 0):

To stop TinyMCE removing an empty element consider adding a non-breaking space   e.g.

```
<div class="clearfix">&nbsp;</div>
```

Wordpress TinyMCE removes any HTML tags without a content. Same rule applies to icons or anything else e.g.:

```
<i class="fa fa-icon">&nbsp;</i>
```

Also, I Strongly advise everyone to use modern CSS technics e.g.:

```
.last:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  font-size: 0;
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've found around this is to add an element with the class hidden with some text in it. Then use the .hidden class to hide that element. Tiny MCE was stripping the non-breaking space from my content.

So, it would look like this:

```
<div class="clearfix"><span class="hidden">Clearfix</span></div>
```